# Rollback to previous migrations does not work when Seed code is present

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We use `Code First Migration` sometimes it is useful to rollback to previous migrations.

Something like `Update-Database -TargetMigration:name_of_migration` do the job most of the time.

But it does not work if some migrations contains `Seed` code.

Error:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.__HistorySeeds_dbo.__MigrationHistory_History_MigrationId_History_ContextKey". 

The conflict occurred in database "MYDB", table "dbo.__HistorySeeds". 
The statement has been terminated.
```

My question is how to proceed in that situation ?

Example below:

```
public partial class AddMyTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "MyTable",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Description = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    CreatedById = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    CreatedTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false)
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.MyTable");
    }

    public void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        context.MyTable.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Description, new MyTable { Description = "Aaaaa", CreatedById = "JOHN.DOE", CreatedTime = DateTime.Now });
        context.MyTable.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Description, new MyTable { Description = "Bbbbb", CreatedById = "JOHN.DOE", CreatedTime = DateTime.Now });
        context.MyTable.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Description, new MyTable { Description = "Ccccc", CreatedById = "JOHN.DOE", CreatedTime = DateTime.Now });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If your seeding is dependent, I would move it inside the Up()/Down() methods: `Sql("INSERT INTO MyTable (Description, CreatedById, CreatedTime) VALUES ("Aaaaa","JOHN.DOE",DateTime.Now);");` then delete the values in Down().

Comment: I know it can be done in the ``Up()/Down()`` methods ``Sql("....")`` but I'm curious if rollback is still possible with the ``Seed()`` method.